# simple tableau case statement to DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, tableau-desktop

I have a simple data structure where I have a bunch of indicators that are assigned an indicator key and name, and indicator values that correspond to those indicators say (indicator_name = sales, key = 48, indicator_value =56000). I would like to write a case statement equivalent in POWERBI so as to create a measure for sales. in tableau this would be as simple as case indicator key when 48 then indicator_value else 0 end

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new column in your table by clicking on the menu as shown below-

[image]

The DAX code for your new column will be as below-

```
test_column = 
if (
    your_table_name[indicator key] = 48, 
    indicator_value,
    0
)
```